# Download the web service response(blob) as pdf in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

**I am trying to download the blob object as pdf,i did nt find exact solution in expo ,please help me to sort out this problem.**

Comment: Have you started? Do you have any code? We wont do the solution for you, but rather help you

Comment: From fetch method i received response(blob),how to store into device folder as pdf in expo, for this file saver is not supporting,Rn-fetch-blob is not suppoorting  for expo ,can u help me for this